# NHibernate Persist previously 'Deleted' object

Tags: nhibernate

I have an NHibernate object which has a child collection mapped as AsBag, Inverse, Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan.

I have scenario where I need to re-persist a deleted object.

Deleting the parent object is fine..the parent and the children are removed from the database.

The issue is, that I need to re-save/persist the deleted object. If I try to call SaveUpdate, I get a StaleObjectStateException, because the Id field is still set to a non-zero value for the parent, and children objects.

Sure, I can force the Id to zero for parent on delete, but then forcing the children's Ids to zero seems cumbersome.

Is there a better strategy for handling this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you `Evict` after you `Delete`, but before you `Flush`, you'll be OK; it will roll off your pending delete.

```
        // Act
        using (ISession session = _factory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.Save(expected);
            session.Flush();

            session.Delete(expected);
            session.Evict(expected);

            tx.Commit();
        }

        using (ISession session = _factory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            actual = session.Get<Person>(expected.Id);

            var count = actual.Roles.Count;
        }

        // Assert
        expected.ShouldHave().AllProperties().EqualTo(actual); // succeeds; record is not deleted or otherwise molested.
```

However, once you flush, there isn't a good way to undo/resave. Figure out how to avoid deleting the object in the first place, avoid flushing between the delete and restore, or rollback the transaction to undo the delete. Another option, if it is OK for the data to be resaved as a new record (so long as the values are retained), then just clone the deleted record and save.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but in this case it won't work....I really need a mechanism where I can delete and re-persist an object graph.

What we've done is:

a. Created an interface with a single method ResetId, which is added to each object that behaves like this.
b. Hook into the PostCommitDeleteEventListeners event, if the object implements the interface we call the ResetId.

Do you foresee any issues with this approach?

Many Thanks

Comment: What is the desired end result? That the deleted graph be saved as if it were brand new?

Comment: In this case yes, when it's been deleted, it might need to be re-persisted; this type of 'transaction' also goes across multiple sessions (it's in a web app). BTW, this isn't a 'Long Running' transaction.

Comment: I would just clone it as I mentioned (just add a `Clone` method, copy and return all the pertinent values, doing likewise for the type at each depth in the graph). The reason I don't recommend your `ResetId` approach is because of `GetHashCode`. If you've implemented your entity correctly, you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, where you compare based on the ID. So, to reset the object you'd have to reset the ID and the hashcode, and the hashcode an instance returns is not supposed to change.

Comment: However, despite the technical minutiae, your suggestion and mine are similar: the instances being resaved need to have the ID re/un-set.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the heads-up it's greatly appreciated.